# Find value of key from javascript JSON Object

Tags: javascript, json

I have this object value

```
var data = {
    "questions": {
        "0": {
            "0": "17",
            "1": "12"
        },
        "1": {
            "0": "22",
            "1": "34"
        },
        "2": {
            "0": "52",
            "1": "61"
        }
    }
}
```

I am trying to get value from these objects as I have tried below things which return me other than what I actually want.

```
alert(Object.keys(data.questions[0])); // Output : 0,1
alert(Object.keys(data.questions[0][0])); // Output : 0
alert(Object.keys(data.questions[0][1])); // Output : 0
```

Anyone can help me find the value of above keys like:

```
questions[0][0] = 17 
questions[0][1] = 12
```

Comment: what you are trying with `Object.keys(data.questions[0][0]`)? where `data.questions[0][0]` is `17` so what you meant with `Object.keys(17)`?

Comment: @KoushikChatterjee `Object.keys(...)` is working for me for count total question and also total parameter in one question now I want to get the value of parameter 0 and parameter 1. Where I am stuck right now.

Comment: console.log(data.questions["0"]["1"]); this should give the results.

Comment: @Dinesh this returns 1 not the value 12.

Comment: @KirankumarDafda check my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try like this.

```js
var data = {
    "questions": {
        "0": {
            "0": "17",
            "1": "12"
        },
        "1": {
            "0": "22",
            "1": "34"
        },
        "2": {
            "0": "52",
            "1": "61"
        }
    }
}

console.log(data.questions["0"]);
console.log(data.questions["0"]["0"]);
console.log(data.questions["0"]["1"]);
```

Comment: @KirankumarDafda did you compare his answer and my answer properly? He actually modified your data and wrote answer.

Comment: Yes, she edited her answer. But both of your answer giving me same response which is [object,object] and 0 and 1

Comment: Then there might be a other problem. Please debug your code.

Answer (score 1):

You get the result without `Object.keys`.

```js
var data = { questions: { 0: { 0: "17", 1: "12" }, 1: { 0: "22", 1: "34" }, 2: { 0: "52", 1: "61" } } };

console.log(data.questions[0]);    // { 0: "17", 1: "12" }
console.log(data.questions[0][0]); // 17
console.log(data.questions[0][1]); // 12
```

For searching a value's path of keys, you could use an iterative and recursive approach by checking all keys and objects.

```js
function findValue(object, value) {
    var p;
    Object.keys(object).some(function (k) {
        var t;
        if (object[k] === value) {
            p = [k];
            return true;
        }
        if (object[k] && typeof object[k] === 'object' && (t = findValue(object[k], value))) {
            p = [k].concat(t);
            return true;
        }
    });
    return p;
}

var data = { questions: { 0: { 0: "17", 1: "12" }, 1: { 0: "22", 1: "34" }, 2: { 0: "52", 1: "61" } } };

console.log(findValue(data, '17'));
console.log(findValue(data, '34'));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: I need Object.key to get length of questions. Also `data.questions[0]` returns `[object,object]`  and another two 0 and 1 value only

Comment: How to get the value of keys which is 17 and 12 for first question.

Answer (score 1):

To get length of any particular question (in your data structure) use

`Object.keys(data.questions["0"])` or `Object.keys(data.questions["1"])`

to get value of any questions use

`data.questions["0"]["0"]` or `data.questions["0"]["1"]` or `data.questions["1"]["0"]` and so on..

Comment: Not working for me `data.questions[0][0]` returns 0 and `data.questions[0][1]` returns 0. while I need 17 and 12

Comment: It should work, try pressing `Run code snippet` button on Nina's answer

Answer (score 0):

Can you change the data structure? If I were you I would change it to the following:

```js
var data = {
  "questions": [
      [17, 22],
      [22, 34],
      [52, 61]
  ]
};

console.log(data.questions[0]); // Output : 17,22
console.log(data.questions[0][0]); // Output : 17
console.log(data.questions[1][1]); // Output : 34
```

Comment: No, I am not able to change response of API so I need to adjust data from this detail only.

Answer (score 0):

To access the first object `["0"]`
To access the first two object : `["0"]["0"]` and so on 
based on the above expression we can access the objects like this

```js
var data = {
    "questions": {
        "0": {
            "0": "17",
            "1": "12"
        },
        "1": {
            "0": "22",
            "1": "34"
        },
        "2": {
            "0": "52",
            "1": "61"
        }
    }
}

console.log(data.questions["0"]);
console.log(data.questions["0"]["0"]);
console.log(data.questions["0"]["1"]);
console.log(data.questions["1"]["1"]);
```